# iterating fetchall() dictionary in for loop isn't working

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I intend to return personalized tokens for each user in database; To do so, I tried to iterate list of users in `for` loop and check whether the current user is in db table or not, if yes `GET` method would return token value. I used `postgresql` and `psycopg2`, I used `fetchall()` to get all instances in db table, but I need to iterate each row and to chek whether it is in db or not. I tried of for loop, but I have following error at endpoint:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/token?username=tom%20hardy&password=password3' 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/token?username=tom%20hardy&password=password3
```

error message in response body:

```
{
  "message": "Username: tom hardy doesn't exist. You have requested this URI [/token] but did you mean /token ?"
}
```

it is not true because user in request body is actually in db. I assume iterating `fetchall()` dict is not working in below code attempt. how to make this work?

**postgresql DB**:

```
CREATE TABLE authorized_user_table(
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

insert  into authorized_user_table(user_id,username,password) values 
 (1,'jen hank','password'),
(2,'andy roy','password2'),
(3, 'tom hardy', 'password3'),
(4, 'shah khan', 'password4');
```

**my backend code**

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, Namespace
from flask_restplus import abort, fields, inputs, reqparse
from psycopg2 import sql
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import psycopg2, json, request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app) 

credential_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
credential_parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
credential_parser.add_argument('password', type=str)

@api.route('/token')
class Token(Resource):
    @api.response(200, 'Successful')
    @api.doc(description="Generates a authentication token")
    @api.expect(credential_parser, validate=True)
    def get(self):
        args = credential_parser.parse_args()
        username = args.get('username')
        password = args.get('password')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM public.authorized_user_table')
        users = cursor.fetchall()
        for user in users:
            if username != user[1]:   ## user[1] gives username
                api.abort(404, "Username: {} doesn't exist".format(username))
            if password != user[2]:
                api.abort(401, "Wrong password")
            return {"token": generate_token(username)

def generate_token(self, username):
    info = {
        'username': username,
        'creation_time': time()
    }
    token = self.serializer.dumps(info)
    return token.decode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = psycopg2.connect(database='test_db', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost', port="5432")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

iterating `fetchall()` dict still not satisfying in above code. how should I iterate them? any way to get this right? thanks

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am not sure that does trick. Is that as same as what I tried to do? if it does, how to handle exception or db error? can we use `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM public.authorized_user_table WHERE username = %s', user[1] ) ` with conditional statement? thanks

Comment: @snakecharmerb if my above attempt is not optimal, any better way to make it efficient? thanks for your help

Comment: Actually, you could do `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM public.authorized_user_table WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password) )` to get all rows from the db that match the username and password from the request.  Ideally this would return one or zero rows

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong variable name in the original comment

Comment: @snakecharmerb that shouldn't be issue. I get your point but I am wondering how can I validate user whether is in db or not. Would you mind to post workable solution if it is possible? thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in this loop does not work:

```
    for user in users:
        if username != user[1]:   ## user[1] gives username
            api.abort(404, "Username: {} doesn't exist".format(username))
        if password != user[2]:
            api.abort(401, "Wrong password")
```

We are iterating over all the users, but if any user's name doesn't match the name from the request we immediately return a 404. Likewise, if the password doesn't match, we immediately return a 401.

This is better:

```
    ...
    for user in users:
        if username == user[1]:   ## user[1] gives username
            # Assume user names are unique
            # Only check password if the username matches
            if password == user[2]:
                # FIXME: in the question generate_token appears to be 
                # a method of this class, but is outside the class
                return {"token": self.generate_token(username)}
            api.abort(401, "Wrong password")
     api.abort(404, "Username: {} doesn't exist".format(username))
```

However we can do this work in a single database query, by asking the database whether there is a row in the table that matches the user name *and* password from the request.

First of all, let's make sure that no two users can have the same username, by making it *unique* in the database:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_user_name ON authorized_user_table (user_name);
```

Now in the Python code:

```
    ...
    # Count the rows that match username AND password
    cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.authorized_user_table """
                   """WHERE user_name = %s AND user_password = %s""",
                   (username, password))
    # COUNT will always return just one row
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    if user[0] == 1:
        return {"token": self.generate_token(username)}
    # Don't let an attacker know what they have got right or wrong.
    api.abort(401, "Invalid user or password")
```

The above variant returns less information in the event of an error.  This is usually a good idea for login handlers, because if an attacker is guessing usernames and passwords you don't want to let them know whether they have found a valid username.

If you want responses to distinguish between incorrect usernames and passwords, you can combine the two approaches.

```
    ...
    cursor.execute("""SELECT user_password FROM public.authorized_user_table """
                   """WHERE user_name = %s""",
                   (username,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    if not user:
        api.abort(404, "Username: {} doesn't exist".format(username))
    if user[0] == password:
        return {"token": self.generate_token(username)}
    api.abort(401, "Wrong password")
```

Whichever solution you choose, the takeaway is that when matching data with data in a database, you want to avoid fetching lots of rows from the database and matching in your application.  It's usually much faster to let the database do the work, by crafting a suitable query.